# Reg-ex query is too greedy

Tags: regex

Consider the following snippet:

```
<Offering id=1 blah blah templateid=abc something=blah
gretre
rtert
ret
tr
/Offering>

<Offering id=2 blah blah templateid=def something=blah>
gretre
rtert
ret
tr
</Offering>

<Offering id=3 blah blah templateid=ghi something=blah>
gretre
rtert
ret
tr
</Offering>
```

Given that all I know is the template id, I need to return the whole Offering node that contains it. i.e. for templateid=def, I need to return:

```
   <Offering id=2 blah blah templateid=def something=blah>
    gretre
    rtert
    ret
    tr
    </Offering>
```

I've tried all sorts but the closest I can get is something along the lines of `(?s)<Offering.+?templateid=def.+?</Offering>` which returns from the first offering until the end of the offering containing my template id. I understand why but nothing I've tried can fix it. I'm guessing lookarounds but I just can't get it right.

How can I return the whole offering node?

Comment: What kinds of characters are there inside "blah"? Are any characters allowed?

Comment: Does it need to be regex? A document parser would be much safer and more appropriate to the task in hand

Comment: Also, what language are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your regex using negation and I would probably use a word boundary as well.

```
<Offering[^>]*\btemplateid=def[^>]*>[^<]*</Offering>
```

If you have other tags inside of this tag, you could do ...

```
(?s)<Offering[^>]*\btemplateid=def.+?</Offering>
```

Comment: Thanks hwnd, the second regex does exactly what I need :-)
I'd tried to do something similar where I (tried) to negate the closing offering tag like this:
(?s)<Offering[^(</Offering>)]+templateid=def.+?</Offering>
Can you tell me where I went wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work but please notice that I escaped the `/` character, and you may not need to do that depending on what language you're using:

```
(<Offering[^>]* templateid=ghi [^>]*>[^<]*<\/Offering>)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say you "need to return the whole Offering ***node***", the arguably simpler, safer and more readable way would be a DOM parser. I've included examples of how you might do this in JavaScript and PHP below.

PHP

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($testStr); //Only needed if you're loading HTML like in the example which has repeated attributes and other things that could cause errors
$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$templateID = 'def';
$myNode = null;
foreach($body->childNodes as $node)
{
    if($node->nodeName=='offering')
    {
        if($node->attributes->getNamedItem('templateid')->nodeValue == $templateID)
        {
            $myNode = $node;
        }
    }
}
//$id = $myNode->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->nodeValue;
//$html = $doc->saveHTML($myNode)
```

JavaScript

```
var testStr = document.getElementById('str_container').innerHTML;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(testStr,'text/html');
var templateID = 'def';
var myEl = null;
for(var i=0,c=doc.body.children.length;i<c;i++)
{
    if(doc.body.children[i].getAttribute('templateid')===templateID)
    {
        myEl = doc.body.children[i];
    }
}
//var id = myEl.id;
//var html = myEl.outerHTML;
console.log(myEl || 'not found');
```

JavaScript >= IE8

```
var testStr = document.getElementById('str_container').innerHTML;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(testStr,'text/html');
var templateID = 'def';
var myEl = doc.body.querySelector('offering[templateid='+templateID+']');
//var id = myEl.id;
//var html = myEl.outerHTML;
console.log(myEl || 'not found');
```

Comment: Thanks SmokeyPHP - that was plan B but as I'm also using a number of regex patterns to match other strings in the doc I wanted to keep it consistent.